# How to store the below string in a variable as it is?

Tags: java

How to store the below string in a variable as it is, using java?
I am getting this string as it is from csv file and I want to fetch only parameters from the string. However I am facing issue as the Colon is not allowing the string to store in String or Array of String.
I want to use the below parameters in Post method in Rest Assured.

{ "CompanyName" : "TestCompanyWithAllParams","CommercialId":"AB1C"}

Thanks,

Comment: The colons don't prevent anything. Perhaps you forgot to escape the `\"` double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the string into variable like this:

```
String var = "{ \"CompanyName\" : \"TestCompanyWithAllParams\",\"CommercialId\":\"AB1C\"}";
```

You have to be only careful about double quotes (`"`), as they are considered as start and terminator of the string. They must be escaped with back-slash (`\"`).

Answer (score 0):

String str = "{ \"CompanyName\" : \"TestCompanyWithAllParams\",\"CommercialId\":\"AB1C\"}";
        System.out.println(str);

It will work.

No issues with :